Using nodejs to render a page on the server side
is there any ready-made library for NodeJS that will allow me to render the page on the server side? This is a ready-made page that uses many references that I would like to not be visible to the user. That's why I thought of moving the rendering from the client side to the server side. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything, I'm counting on some tips and thank you in advance.
I tried to use SSR proxy libraries but unfortunately it did not give the desired effect.

What do you mean by "references"?  Maybe something like https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html is what you want?

thanks for the answer. I will clarify. This is a SPA-type website. Depending on the activity performed, Ajax requests are sent to different endpoints. I would like it not to be visible to the user and the entire JS handling would be handled by the server and the user could only see the end result. Unfortunately, rewriting the entire page is not an option. Another issue is that some JS processes in the code are very burdensome, if the server could take care of it it would be much more efficient for the user.

This doesn't sound like a valid reason, honestly. If there's heavy processing, it can be done on server side or in a worker. If there are some requests that shouldn't be exposed, they can be proxied on server side. But "would like to not be visible" doesn't sound like there's an objective requirement for such a drastic decision. Not to mention this will ruin SPA's UX. There are prerender services including self-hosted ones, but they usually provide SSR in addition to CSR, not as a replacement. They involve a headless browser (puppeteer, playwright), which you can use yourself for this purpose
